# Jquery code block with if statment not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to show fancybox only once per user browser session. For this  i thought of using `jquery-cookie` along with other logic to show fancy box window only one.

But problem in this code below is that it never check either of the `if (visited == 'yes')` block;

For testing i put three alert and i always get one alert gets active i.e `alert('1');`

```
 if (window.showMessage) {
        alert('1');
        var visited = $.cookie('visited2');
        if (visited == 'yes') {
            alert('a');
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('b');
            //openFancybox();
            $("a.fancybox-messageboard").fancybox({
                width: 600,
                height: 440,
                closeClick: false,
                hideOnOverlayClick: false,
                href: imgPath,
                helpers: {
                    overlay: { closeClick: false} // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
                }
            }).trigger('click');
            $.cookie('visited2', 'yes', { expires: 7 });
        }

    }
```

I also get following error

```
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
var visited = $.cookie('visited2');
```

Comment: Have you added `jquery-cookie` plugin? Error clearly suggest not.

Comment: You must add `<script src="js/jquery_cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` after jquery

Comment: Yes u have added `jquery-cookie.js` file

Comment: try wrapping your js with `$(document).ready(function() { /*code here*/ });`

Comment: actually i have few functions which are wrapped around `$(document).ready(function() { /*code here*/ });`. My be `jquery.cookie.js` is not being called properly

Comment: This code works fine only in firefox private mode, but not on other browsers liek IE or chrome..